# What steps needed to decode a Base64 binary?

Tags: disassembly

I tried to decode it by Base64 but still didn't understand the result

```
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
```

Comment: What is the binary, where did you get it?

Comment: Its not even a shellcode.

Answer (score 2):

The data you give - whatever it is - doesn't comply to Base32.

The following script decodes your encoded string with Python3.

```
!/usr/bin/env python3

import base64

encoded = "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"

with open("test.bin", "wb") as f:
    f.write(base64.b64decode(
        encoded
        ))
```

... simply replace `base64.b64decode` by a call to `base64.b32decode` and you'll get an error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/base64.py", line 205, in b32decode
    raise binascii.Error('Incorrect padding')
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

Long story short: it seems to be Base64-encoded data.

```
$ file test.bin 
test.bin: data
```

... oh and one more fact corroborates this. If we insert the following line before the `with` but after the assignment to `encoded`:

```
print(len(set(x for x in encoded)))
```

... we get `64` as output. So 64 distinct characters were used in the string.

Uploading the file [to VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/2f686422c57a1ae0d40dce8e4a25a528854b037b55043a46111029f42e699ba1/details) yields nothing either. Usually these antimalware engines are fairly good at detecting even esoteric file types.

So if you want to know what sort of data that might be you should perhaps add more context into your question or ask a new one.